# Why I am getting Invalid escape error only in vivo browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, next.js

This vivo browser has made my life difficult as a developer. All my styling is messed up in this browser only. Recenlty, in my **nextjs** **Laravel** website's shop page the product feed is not rendering even though I am not using any regx in the code but still throwing this error.
[image]

And when I tried to paste this message in browser it points to file and says file not found.